# Contrapositive with Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$
\forall n \in  \mathbb{N}  \ P(n)\ \implies \exists p \in \mathbb{N} \ G(n)
$$

Is the contrapositive correct?

$$
\exists  n \in \mathbb {N}\  \neg G(n) \ \implies \forall n \in \mathbb {N}\  \neg P(n) 
$$
How would you directly prove this?
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}( \neg\mathrm{Prime}(n)\ \implies \exists p \in \mathbb{N}(\mathrm{Prime}(p) \wedge\ (p\leq \sqrt n)\ \wedge\ (p ∣ n)))
$$

Comment: Do you mean $p(n)$ and $g(p)$? The way it is now your quantifiers don't actually do anything.

Comment: Fixed the question.

Comment: The negation of $\forall$ is $\exists$ and vice versa.

Comment: thatts what im asking.. do the quantifiers negative with contrapositive or not

Answer (score 1):

The negation laws for quantifiers are as follows:
$$\lnot\forall x \varphi \iff \exists x \neg \varphi \\
\lnot\exists x \varphi \iff \forall x \neg \varphi$$

So the contrapositive of 
$$
\forall n \in  \mathbb{N}  \ P(n)\ \implies \exists p \in \mathbb{N} \ G(n)
$$

is

$$
\neg \exists p \in \mathbb{N} \ G(n) \implies \neg\forall n \in  \mathbb{N}  \ P(n)\ 
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
 \forall p \in \mathbb{N} \ \neg G(n) \implies \exists n \in  \mathbb{N}  \ \neg P(n)\ 
$$
Now, regarding the expression at the end of your post, you wrote: $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \neg\mathrm{Prime}(n)\ \implies \exists p \in \mathbb{N}(\mathrm{Prime}(p) \wedge\ (p\leq \sqrt n)\ \wedge\ (p ∣ n))$$
But this is ambiguous because it isn't clear whether the consequent is within the scope of the $\forall$ in the beginning. If it isn't within the scope of the $\forall$ in the beginning, then the consequent contains a free variable ($n$). I think what you meant to say was:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}( \neg\mathrm{Prime}(n)\ \implies \exists p \in \mathbb{N}(\mathrm{Prime}(p) \wedge\ (p\leq \sqrt n)\ \wedge\ (p ∣ n)))$$
The steps you would want to take to prove this would be to use the fact that $(P \implies Q)$ is equivalent to $(\neg P \lor Q)$ to rewrite the expression as: 
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}(\mathrm{Prime}(n)\ \lor \exists p \in \mathbb{N}(\mathrm{Prime}(p) \wedge\ (p\leq \sqrt n)\ \wedge\ (p ∣ n)))$$
But then you'll notice that this is false for $n = 1$, since $1$ is neither prime, nor is there a prime number that divides $1$.